# ThreeJS face color not isn't applied

Tags: three.js

I've been learning three.js and have run into an issue. I have copied a very simple example directly from three.js's own website: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Face3

It has you create a material with a green color:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color : 0x00cc00 } );
```

Then create a triangle with a yellow color:

```
    //create a new face using vertices 0, 1, 2
    var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
    var color = new THREE.Color( 0xffaa00 ); // <-- YELLOW COLOR
    var materialIndex = 0;
    var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, materialIndex );
```

Setting the yellow color of the face does nothing, and I don't understand why. I also tried not setting the material color, but then it just shows as white. How can I set the color of each face when I create it. [Here's a JSFiddle of the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/rlouie/qu0mvw4j/20/)

Comment: You need to assign `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` in the material constructor, to make sure face3 color is used. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgts5jch/)

Comment: In the latest (r116) revision, it's enough to use `vertexColors: true`. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/face-coloring-a-inbuilt-threejs-geometry/13565/7?u=prisoner849